# Wie werden umgangssprachliche Auslassungen schriftlich dargestellt?

Tags: colloquial, spelling

In der gesprochenen Umgangssprache werden häufig Vokale ausgelassen, zum Beispiel beim Wort "*es*":

> Morgen soll **es** regnen.

Die Frage ist nun, wie dies beim Aufschreiben aussieht. Ich würde sagen, der ausgelassene Vokal wird durch einen Apostroph (**'**) ersetzt, aber was geschieht mit dem Leerzeichen?

> Morgen soll 's regnen.

oder etwa

> Morgen soll's regnen.

Welches (wenn überhaupt eins) ist korrekt?

Comment: Da ich keine Quelle angeben kann, und es v.a. um die Leerstelle geht als Kommentar: Für ständig praktizierte Auslassungen wird der Apostroph unterschlagen, während er bei seltenen gesetzt werden soll: "Wolln wir 3 und 4 addier'n?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bei *'s* für *es* sagt der [Duden (Regel 14 Punkt 4)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph#K14), dass man kein Leerzeichen setzt. Der Apostroph ist dabei entbehrlich:

> Wie gehts (auch: geht's) dir?

In anderen Fällen verwendet der Duden ein Leerzeichen: Das erste Beispiel in besagter Regel 14 ist

> So 'n Blödsinn!

Ich persönlich würde das Leerzeichen hier nicht setzen. Eine Regel dazu habe ich leider nicht gefunden.

Comment: Ich vermute, dass das Leerzeichen nur gesetzt werden kann, wenn sich durch Leerzeichen plus Apostroph die Aussprache ändern kann: „So ’n“ kann einen Glottisschlag (?) enthalten, „für’n“ eher nicht.

Comment: @Philipp: Ah, ich habe an Silben gedacht, aber dabei Glottisschläge vergessen - danke! Aber würdest Du bei "So 'n" wirklich einen Glottisschlag unterbringen?

Answer (score 0):

> Morgen soll's regnen.

ist korrekt. Siehe dazu: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostroph#Auslassungszeichen

Comment: Ah, danke. Ich sehe grade dass dort auch dies steht: "Was für ’n Blödsinn!"; müsste es nicht dann auch heißen: "Was für’n Blödsinn!"?

Comment: Die direkte Rede dient dazu, das gesprochene Wort wiederzugeben. Meiner Erfahrung nach wendet man die Regeln der Rechtschreibung deshalb etwas freizügiger an, z. B. empfehlen manchen Autoren in Stil-Lehrbüchern, das Apostroph als Auslassungszeichen wegzulassen, weil es angeblich den Lesefluss behindert. Das wäre dann: Morgen solls regnen. Das und die Form mit dem Leerzeichen vor dem Apostroph (die seltsam aussieht) wird sicher niemand als Fehler anstreichen. Aber wenn du hundertprozentig regelkonform schreiben willst, schreib: Morgen soll's regnen.